# how to install api(youtube-api-search ) in spfx&React project created by yeoman-generator

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts

I created my project wth yeoman template generator;

```
yo @microsoft/sharepoint
```

command(react choosen as JS framework). than installed youtube search api

```
npm install youtube-api-search
```

so far everything seems ok.
[image]

But when I try to use api in project I encounter with "Cannot find module 'youtube-api-search'." here error messages in command line when I run "gulp serve";

I only added `import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';` line to default code and I see these exceptions in commandline

[image]

here the lines if you cant see the image;

```
[11:02:03] Error - typescript - src\webparts\helloWorld\components\HelloWorld.tsx(6,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'youtube-api-search'.
[11:02:03] Error - 'typescript' sub task errored after 122 ms
 "TypeScript error(s) occurred."
```

I also checked youtube-api-search package exist under node_modules directory. so this error message makes no sense at all.

why does this error occurs here and more important how can I able to use third party apis(its not specific for youtube-api-search I think) in yeoman generated project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install also TypeScript definitions for `youtube-api-search` to make it work. TypeScript should understand where to find your module. Since no typings provided you see this error.

I didn't find typings for this particular module (may be the name is different, give it a try), so in order to fix it you need to use commonjs style for loading modules.
Change it to: `var YTSearch: any = require('youtube-api-search')`

Comment: Im shocked.. I tried your way and it seems ok now I wonder what if I want to push template to use typings I mean, does it works if I simply run "npm i typings". and what about side effects ? I mean what possible causes this brings in ?  But first of all, Thank you so much!

Comment: I would say that by now it's total mess with a way to provide a typescript definitions for the project. In the past there was `tsd`, then [`typings`](https://github.com/typings/typings) and now `@types`. Yes it will work and normally no side effects.

Comment: Hi Sergei, can you help me about this post; "http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/205743/spfx-r-c-post-method-sphttpclient-configurations-v1-undefined-exception"  appreciated for your helps