# SPFx R.C. post method, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1 undefined exception

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-list

I am try to convert [this old school example](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/sharepoint-crud). It was drop 3, now I need to convert it to SPFx RC version;

```
private createItem(): void {
    this.getListItemEntityTypeName()
      .then((listItemEntityTypeName: string): Promise<Response> => {
        const body: string = JSON.stringify({
          '__metadata': {
            'type': listItemEntityTypeName
          },
          'Title': `Item ${new Date()}`
        });
        return this.props.httpClient.post(`${this.props.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.props.listName}')/items`, {
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
            'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'odata-version': ''
          },
          body: body
        })
```

only diff is shape of post. changed to;

```
private createItem(): void { 
    this.getListItemEntityTypeName()
      .then((listItemEntityTypeName: string): Promise<Response> => {

        return this.props.httpClient.post(`${this.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.props.listName}')/items`, 
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
        "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/test14jan"
      })
  }
```

method simple adding an item to list in domain. myweb part running in server(https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx)
each time I refresh the page this error seems in console(before call any method)
[image]

"403 forbidden" can you help me to solve this please? I am pretty sure this cause my problem because I am able to get items from list via this get method;

```
this.props.httpClient.get(`${this.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.props.listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id`, 
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
```

so something wrong with post. using oldschool header object not works with spfx RC.0 as you know

**EDITED:**
Here is exception;
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is nothing to do with javascript error you mentioned (`suiteserviceproxy.aspx`), because this error doesn't related to SPFx. For example I'm also see this error on my dev tenant on many different pages (not only `workbench.aspx`). I tend to think this is some misconfiguration with other Office 365 services, but for dev tenant that's OK.

For you question, I think you need to fix two things:

1. Use `SPHttpClientConfigurations` instead of `SPHttpClient` (like they mentioned under [release notes for RC0](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Release-Notes-RC0#update-your-webpart-code))
2. You didn't provide request body for post, which is required if you want to update an item.

So you updated code will be:

import required modules:

```
import {SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientConfigurations} from '@microsoft/sp-http'; 

 private createItem(): void {
    this.getListItemEntityTypeName()
      .then((listItemEntityTypeName: string): Promise<Response> => {
        const body: string = JSON.stringify({
          '__metadata': {
            'type': listItemEntityTypeName
          },
          'Title': `Item ${new Date()}`
        });
        return this.props.httpClient.post(`${this.props.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.props.listName}')/items`, SPHttpClientConfigurations.v1, {
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
            'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'odata-version': ''
          },
          body: body
        })
```

**UPD**
I guess you are not using latest version of npm packages and typescript definitions. Consider screen from my env (post accepts three arguments):

[image]

When migrating to RC0 I found it **MUCH** easier to run everything from scratch and then add missing files. Otherwise you might have total mess (like I had) with different versions of modules and ts errors.

First of all you need to update yo generator for SPFx:
`npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint`

Then in a clean folder run `yo @microsoft/sharepoint`. Select your template (React or No JS framework).
Then start adding missing files and check if it works now.

Comment: Hello, ty for response. I edited post as you said but its not match with new signature post method of RC. Did you tried this before ? How did you make it work ?

Comment: @TyForHelpDude: Please take a look at the update

Comment: You didn't copy my code correctly. Take a note, that the last third parameter should be enclosed with `{ }`, on your screen it doesn't enclosed.

Comment: Yes You are rigth, I mistype the headers paramters now it works. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Sergei, please check this post when you are available;
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/206043/skip-n-items-take-n-items-from-sharepoint-list-rest-api