# Access other Site collections in SPFx web parts

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, spfx, spfx-webparts

We have a requirement to convert one of the existing provider hosted app functionality to spfx webpart.

The provider hosted app implemented using App only calls to access other site collection in the tenant.

Now I want to know is there any way in SPFx webpart to access other site collections?

Any suggestions or reference links are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done it, but it is possible. You need to use SPHttpClientConfigurations instead of SPHttpClient. There is an example of using it in this answer to another question: [SPFx R.C. post method, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1 undefined exception](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/205743/spfx-r-c-post-method-sphttpclient-configurations-v1-undefined-exception)

Ref: [Adding Items to a list in another sitecollection :- SharePoint Framework (SPFx) Webpart](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/91f7431c-0462-4af7-b46f-ecc51efa0dd6/adding-items-to-a-list-in-another-sitecollection-sharepoint-framework-spfx-webpart?forum=appsforsharepoint)

Comment: BTW, both ot the references I provided say use SPHttpClientConfigurations instead of SPHttpClient, so I said it too.  But looking at the example, it's more accurate to say in conjunction with.